# Babel build causing Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, eslint, es6-module-loader, babel-loader

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but when I bundle my code using web pack and babel. One of linter within babel throwing a left-hand side in an assignment expression. I try the same line without bundling and nobody complain and it works fine not sure if anyone has any input that would be a great help. It should be something small I am missing.

this.m_checkpointObject.MetaData(key) = value;

Here is the actual code.

if you put this line in babel in their try it out page then it throws same error I get in my side. https://babeljs.io/repl

```
class checkPointTimer {
    constructor() { 
        this.m_checkpointObject = null;
        try {
            this.m_checkpointObject = window.external.DiscernObjectFactory("CHECKPOINT");
        } catch (exe) {         
            log.error("Unable to create checkpoint object via window.external.DiscernObjectFactory('CHECKPOINT')");
            return this;
        }
        return this;
    }
    setClassName(className) {
        this.m_checkpointObject && (this.m_checkpointObject.ClassName = className);
        return this;
    };
    setProjectName(projectName) {
        this.m_checkpointObject && (this.m_checkpointObject.ProjectName = projectName);
        return this;
    };
    setEventName(eventName) {
        this.m_checkpointObject && (this.m_checkpointObject.EventName = eventName);
        return this;
    };
    setSubEventName(subEventName) {
        this.m_checkpointObject && (this.m_checkpointObject.SubEventName = subEventName);
        return this;
    };
    publish(){
        this.m_checkpointObject && this.m_checkpointObject.Publish();
    };
    addMetaData(key, value) {
        if (this.m_checkpointObject && key && value){
        try {
            this.m_checkpointObject.MetaData(key) = value
        } catch (e) {
            log.error(e)
            log.error("Error adding MetaData [" + key + "] = " + value + "; on CheckpointTimer");
            return this;
        }
        return this;
        }
    };
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Is that snippet from your actual code? What are you expecting it to do? You're calling a function and then somehow trying to assign to it, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Show your actual code.

Comment: @loganfsmyth it is working fine if i don't go through bundle process.

Comment: @ravi No, it should definitely not work, it's a syntax error. How do you run this code?

Comment: @Bergi - what i did is - i remove that line and ran through babel loader so it bundles successfully then i added that line in my bundle code then i run in the browser. it did work and i see all results fine. So not sure what kind of syntax you are talking about?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: i am using IE11.

Comment: @FelixKling i did post the entire code. Any idea what kind of syntax i need to use in order to bypass that error?

Comment: If this is the code you wrote, then `this.m_checkpointObject.MetaData(key) = value` is simply wrong. You cannot *assign* to the return value of a function call. This has nothing to do with Babel. We cannot suggest a fix since we don't know what any of these values are nor what you intend to do with in that line.

Comment: That is reason i don't understand the problem here. if i put line after bundle code then everything work as expected. This throw error when i am trying to bundle the code. So i guess it has to do something with babel loader that i am using to bundle code.

Comment: @FelixKling - Metadata is a function set key/value pair and it is defined CHECKPOINT library. Basically, i am just trying to assign key, value to Metadata function. is that answer your question? Can you suggest fix option if you think the assignment is completely wrong?

Comment: The code you have is not valid JS code, but it is allowed by some engines. That said, it will always throw an exception when it run anyway. You cannot assign to a function return value, only a variable or a property. I'd expect something like that to be more like `this.m_checkpointObject.MetaData(key, value);`, but without knowing what your `MetaData` function does, it's impossible to say.

Comment: thanks. i already try that but it didn't work. yes so MetaData is defined within some outside method which i don't have control have to see and look. Orginally code is written using property type method and i converted into ES6 class base.

Comment: *"So i guess it has to do something with babel loader that i am using to bundle code."* While something like `foo() = bar` is valid *syntax*, you will get a runtime error when the code is executed. Presumably Babel just tells you that this code is wrong before it is even executed. It's a feature, not a bug ;) You have to read the documentation of whatever library you are using to find the right way to *set* a value.